# VB.NET one line code to create array of Excel cell values

Tags: arrays, excel, vb.net, cell, one-liner

I'm trying to replicate this VBA code in VB.NET

[image]

which gives this as result

[image]

how can i do this with **one line of code** in VB.NET?

(I already know to do this with iterations and arrays)

Thanks a lot to everyone who will reply!

Comment: Although I don't recommend it, as it is not so readable, you can put multiple statements on one line by separating them with colons, e.g., `For i = 1 To 10 : Console.WriteLine(i) : Next`. So you could use the method you already know.

Answer (score 1):

First off, don't try and reproduce that VBA code. It's bad and will give you problems - someone's used an unqualified range so there's no telling what data you're doing to get from that.

For a one-liner in VB.Net, you could just `Cast` the range array using the `Object` type and call the `ToArray()` method - remember that you'd need to `DirectCast` the range to a 2D `Object` array first to access the `Cast` method. Something like this (using a qualified range):

```
Dim a = DirectCast(ws.Range("A1:C1").Value, Object(,)).Cast(Of Object).ToArray()
```

[image]

In VBA, if only one cell is defined in the range (eg "A1") then the value type is a Variant rather than an array of Variants, so any attempt to reference it as an array will throw an error. The same would occur in this VB code if you only referenced one cell.